# How to sort a list in Keystone.js?

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I've a model in keystone

```
var keystone = require('keystone');

/**
 * Logs Model
 * ===================
 */
var Logs = new keystone.List('log', {
    map: { name: 'clientname' },
    track: true,
    noedit: true,
});

Logs.add({
    clientname: { type: String, trim: true },
    ingredientName: { type: String, trim: true, lowercase: true },
    upc: { type: String, trim: true },
    sku: { type: String, trim: true },
    handle: { type: String, trim: true },
    status: { type: String, trim: true },
    method: { type: String, trim: true },
    url: { type: String, trim: true },
    date: { type: Date },
});

/**
 * Registration
 */
Logs.defaultColumns = 'url, clientname, status, date';
Logs.register();
```

The default sorting of this data is by date, I want it to be as per clientname in a descending order.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: have u checked https://keystonejs.com/documentation/database/  Drilldown Example ?

Comment: @DebanjanB not sure why you deleted my answer as it directly answered question asked by SushantK. Oh well.. List object offers defaultSort method. So in your case,   Logs.defaultSort = '-clientname'   would suffice.